# Get result as Array in Antd Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I want my form to submit price data as an array format, currently, my form has a map, look like

```
{data.Type && 
    <div>
      {data.Type.map((datamapped)=> 

        <div key={datamapped._id}>
        <p>{datamapped.TypeName}</p>

           <Form.Item>

          {getFieldDecorator(`price.${datamapped._id}.basePrice`)(
            <Input placeholder="Base Price"/>,
          )}

          {getFieldDecorator(`price.${datamapped._id}.higherPrice`)(
            <Input placeholder="Higher Price"/>,
          )}

        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  }
```

Here I mapping my **Type** here and included, basePrice and higherPrice fields

result is  :

```
price: 
        { 
           '5dc2913cf9e2372b11db4252': { basePrice: '0', higherPrice: '0' },
           '5dc2a109f9e2372b11db4253': { basePrice: '0', higherPrice: '0' } 
        },
```

I want the above result as an array format how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try change `datamapped._id` to `[index]`

```
{data.Type && 
    <div>
      {data.Type.map((datamapped, index)=> 

        <div key={datamapped._id}>
        <p>{datamapped.TypeName}</p>

           <Form.Item>

          {getFieldDecorator(`price[${index}].basePrice`)(
            <Input placeholder="Base Price"/>,
          )}

          {getFieldDecorator(`price[${index}].higherPrice`)(
            <Input placeholder="Higher Price"/>,
          )}

        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

Another way to get values as an array is to provide an array as FormItem name attribute like this:

```
<FormItem name={['wrapperName', index, 'propertyName']}>
    <Input/>,
</FormItem>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var json = {
  price: {
    "5dc2913cf9e2372b11db4252": { basePrice: "0", higherPrice: "0" },
    "5dc2a109f9e2372b11db4253": { basePrice: "0", higherPrice: "0" }
  }
};

json.price = Object.entries(json.price);
console.log(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

## my Dynamic Form's note

`antd@3.x`

```
const MyForm = ({ form = {} }) => {
  const { getFieldValue, getFieldDecorator } = form;
  const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState({});
  const add = ()=>{
    // 
    defaultData.price.push({basePrice: 'zz',
      higherPrice: 'hzz',key: new Date().getTime()})
  }
  return (
    <Form>
      <Form.Item>
        {Array.isArray(defaultData.price) && // 
          defaultData.price.map((datamapped, index) => {
            return (
              <div key={datamapped.id||datamapped.key}>
                {getFieldDecorator(`price[${index}].basePrice`, { // 
                  initialValue: datamapped.basePrice,
                })(<Input placeholder="Base Price" />)}

                {getFieldDecorator(`price[${index}].higherPrice`, {
                  initialValue: datamapped.higherPrice,
                })(<Input placeholder="Higher Price" />)}
              </div>
            );
          })}
      </Form.Item>
      <Button onClick={add}> + </Button>
    </Form>
  );
};

export default Form.create()(MyForm);
```

### data structure

```sh
|-- price array[object]
  |-- basePrice string
  |-- higherPrice string
```

### must use useState to assist setFieldsValue

```js
const [defaultData, setDefaultData] = useState({})
setDefaultData({
  price: [
    {
      basePrice: 'xx',
      higherPrice: 'hxx',
    },
    {
      basePrice: 'yy',
      higherPrice: 'hyy',
    },
  ],
});
```

> ⚠️ setFieldsValue only works in the first calling